# Configure multiple monitors setup without XOrg

Tags: xorg, display

Sometimes I need to work with my setup w/o X, so that, for example, `xrandr` will not be available. Typically, I have a laptop and a bigger monitor attached to it, however, laptop's screen resolution is higher... the default mode for my setup appears to be "mirroring", so both the big monitor and the laptop will try to display the same picture, but it will be clipped on the big monitor.

Is there any way to disable one of the monitors (w/o physically disconnecting them?) or, is there a way to control the resolution (I don't mind them both being active at the same time, the clipping is the real problem).

Answer (score 0):

Many laptops have a function toggle button that allows you to switch between internal monitor and external monitor, which on my laptop is F5:

[image]

This allows we to switch off the internal display if connected to an external display.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work (I do have this key, but it doesn't do anything, not even when I run X).

Comment: @wvxvw what laptop is it? and are their any bios settings mentioning displays? On mine I have to use the Fn + F5 combination to get it to work...

Comment: It's a ThinkPad T480. I don't want to reboot it to look into BIOS settings... The key is F7.

Comment: its F7 on my old Thinkpad X41 - and I've noticed that Fn+F7 does make any difference when it's on its docking station...

Comment: I'm connected using USB Mini-Dock, maybe that's the problem... but I don't have other docking stations to try atm.